# In an ASP.NET MVC solution, how can I assemble multiple Word templates components into a single Microsoft word document?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

Our system inserts components --dynamically generated blocks of html-- throughout a text (like a report or article).

The components are MVC partial views that are inserted as needed while looping through the text paragraphs, like so:

```
    @foreach (Paragraph p in Model.TextComponent.InputText.Paragraphs){
        @if ((Model.HeaderComponent != null))
            {
                @Html.Partial("_HeaderComponent", Model.HeaderComponent)
            }
        @if ((Model.NDAComponent != null))
            {
                @Html.Partial("_NDAComponent", Model.NDAComponent)       
            }
    }
```

We’d like to use the same logic to assemble docx files but have not been able to find any examples of this. We have been working with [TemplateEngine.dotx](https://github.com/UNIT6-open/TemplateEngine.Docx), which is great for the formatting of templates, but we haven’t figured out how to split the template into partial views the way we can with MVC partial views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openXML sdk.

Following code can help to copy content of one word document into other document.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(OutputFile, true))
        {

MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
           AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk =
            mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
            AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
        AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

        mainPart.Document
            .Body
            .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
            .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Open XML SDK on the server side to assemble open XML documents, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.